# Router login problem

Tags: router

My netgear router works fine on ethernet and wifi, but I cannot get the login page to change my password. My desktop was recently replaced. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I need to find the ip of my router. I have used the usual 192.168.0.1 etc: without success.

Comment: For Netgear routers, you can usually use the URL www.routerlogin.net

Answer (score 1):

Usually your router is the gateway address. So executing

```
netstat -rn|grep "^0.0.0.0"
```

should give you the IP (second field) of the router

Comment: Thank you for suggestions I will try tomorrow when I get back to desktop.

Comment: Hi tried this morning. This is what I get back.  0.0.0.0         10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
Where do I go from here please?

Comment: Hi tried this morning. This is what I get back.  0.0.0.0         10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
Where do I go from here please?  The first  www.routerlogin.net  took me to login instructiuons which I have tried before. I have read that DHPC has something to do with it but I am not sure?

Comment: Hi Romeo, Got in at last. Using  www.routerlogin.net.  I have just found out something strange. I am using Firefox. If I use the Google line under the main Firefox login line it does not work? I used the top Firefox line and I logged in perfectly? Never had the problem before.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @roanantelope You should [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/963838/edit) to add details. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. However, your question is not directly related to Ubuntu and you might get better results by asking it on [su].